# javaws app using javax.comm API does not see environment variables on Linux x64

Tags: java

I have a Java application that accesses serial ports using Serialio.jar and the javax.comm API. Making the switch from 32-bit Java to 64-bit has posed some problems.  The example code is similar to what is used to communicate with the serial/usb devices:

```
Enumeration portIdentifiers = javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
while (portIdentifiers.hasMoreElements()) {
    javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier pid = (javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier) portIdentifiers.nextElement();
    System.out.println("name: " + pid.getName());
}
```

When I run this code with ***java*** I have to add the `-DSERIAL_PORT_LIST=/dev/ttyS1:/dev/ttyS1` command line option to expose the serial port list.  That works fine.

But when I run this code with ***javaws*** using `-J-DSERIAL_PORT_LIST=/dev/ttyS1:/dev/ttyS1` in the command line, I get this error:

```
getPortList: port discovery not currently supported on this platform.
Options:
A) addPortName can be used to build a list of device names 
B) java -DSERIAL_PORT_LIST=COM1;COM2;COM3
or java -DSERIAL_PORT_LIST=/dev/ttyS0:/dev/ttyS1
```

So far using the addPortName function causes the whole thing to core dump.  Is there a simpler way to get javaws to see the SERIAL_PORT_LIST value?

Comment: Have you tried using a JNLP file to pass in the JVM args? I imagine this is a client app you are trying to launch.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932530/how-to-pass-unsafe-arguments-to-the-jvm-of-a-java-webstart-application